# GMAIL API - Does it support access using service accounts and a single access token

Tags: gmail-api, google-oauth

Does the GMail API Support service accounts?

I have tried using the service accounts to get access tokens, however when using that access token, I get a "failed precondition" error.

On searching, I found that this error is bacause the service account does not have a gmail mailbox, so I should be using the "sub" field in the JWT with a user in the domain.

However, when using the sub field and authorizing the service account for Gmail Scopes, I do not get a access token. It says "Invalid grant, bad request"

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Update: I have managed to get the Token when using the sub field and using the token to make requests.

However, I cannot use one token to access data for all the users. Delegating domain wide access would mean to me that I can get one token and access all the users data.

Currently, I need to use the Service account and each user in the sub field to get access tokens for each user spearately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make the single auth call with sub= for each user you want to access to get the token before you call the Gmail API for a different user.  That is how oauth2 domain-wide delegation works:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

The "one token can access all users in the domain" is a horrible security practice that most Google APIs are phasing out (imagine if that token gets phished!).

Comment: I would think that the whole point of a service account was to avoid getting access tokens for each user, as it is a huge performance overhead getting access tokens for all users every hour.

In that case it is better to use refresh tokens for each user, as that request looks light weight than the request using a Service Account

Comment: It seems hard to believe just getting the token for a user is that much overhead (it's a single HTTP call / user, right?).  But yes, depending on what you're doing and how many users you have, getting refresh tokens may be worthwhile (those still have to be exchanged for an access token even if it's handled transparently by your client library, right? :-p)